# Retrofit debug, generate network request information

Tags: android, networking, retrofit

I am using retrofit to make some network request, but not sure about which @annotation to use, I managed to have successful request using PostMan Utility but cannot get it correct on the android app. Thus I want to debug from the network inspector.

How can I generate a log/report similar as the one below using my android app/emulator?

```
POST /path/to/api/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: [length]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=iSBcxYW-SeE_dubqNJw3p6PP59WbDOAj

--iSBcxYW-SeE_dubqNJw3p6PP59WbDOAj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

test
--iSBcxYW-SeE_dubqNJw3p6PP59WbDOAj--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the loglevel to see the log in your restadapter for retrofit:-

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(your_url_endpoint)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setLog(new AndroidLog("your log tag"))
            .build();
```